# Mountpoint for static mounts

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have a new Server with multiple hard drives (four of them). It's running Debian and I am currently installing it. Now I want to mount the HDDs according to the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

I found two possible locations: `/mnt` but it is for temporarily mounted filesystems. The other one is `/media`, but it is reserved for removable media such as CD-ROMs.

So where can I mount the the HDDs to? (static using fstab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know you can mount drives anywhere you like. If you want to do it according to FHS, it depends of the data which you want to store on the disks. If it's data for a webserver, `/srv/www` would probably be a good idea. If you want to mostly store log files, it'd be a good idea to use `/var/log`.

You could also use LVM (Logical Volume Manager) to create a single, large volume consisting of multiple drives (eg. 4 drives of 500G become one logical disk of 2T). You can then mount this logical volume on `/`. You'd have maximum flexibility then, since you don't have to mount drives at specific mountpoints.